# How to rename objects in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use this API however, I want to use a for loop or map through the strMeasure & strIngredient. Currently those have numbers less than 20 attached. So I am thinking I need to make an array first using a for loop and then implement it? Let me know your thoughts..

```js
const [recipeData, setRecipeData] = useState([]);
const ingredientList = recipeData.map((allData) => {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    arr.push(allData[`strMeasure${i}`] + " " + allData[`strIngredient${i}`]);
  }
  return arr;
});
```

But then do not know how to inject this in my component.

Cheers!

[image: API]

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: My thoughts are "whats for dinner?" and "is it 5 o'clock yet?"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jointing them to a string, I would suggest storing them as key, value pairs within an object. This way it is easier to access the values in your UI.

```js
const allData = {
  strIngredient1: "Beef",
  strIngredient2: "Plain Flour",
  strMeasure1: "1kg",
  strMeasure2: "2 tbs",
  …
};

const items = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i += 1) {
  const strIngredient = allData[`strIngredient${i}`];
  const strMeasure = allData[`strMeasure${i}`];

  items.push({
    ingredient: strIngredient,
    measure: strMeasure,
  });
}

// const items = [
//   {
//     ingredient: "Beef",
//     measure: "1kg",
//   },
//   …
// ];
```

After you transformed your data, you can pass it easily to your component

```
function Recipe(props) {
  const { items } = props.items;

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.ingredient}>
          {item.ingredient}: {item.measure}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

<Recipe items={items} />;
```

Comment: thank you so much Marco! Would you have to know the items coming in to have defined allData? I was playing around last night and got something very similar to what you mentioned. Feel like I need to map this again into another component?here is my screen shot -> https://ibb.co/FXwWcLg

Comment: You are very welcome, Sylwia. I think you are mixing up two concepts. One is the data transformation and the second is the data display. In your example above, why do you need `useState`? Your screenshot looks fine to me. You transform your data and map over it to render a component for each item. If you share an interactive like to CodePen or CodeSandbox, I'm happy to help you :)

Comment: haha this can be an actuallity for sure, I only started to program in Nov. 

I was thinking to useState for the axios result to remove it from that equation and to use it below in the component.

I have made a CodeSandBox and here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-leaf-8snofv
github: https://github.com/SylviaMakuch/the-cookbook


the component we are speaking about is Recipe.js and the id I used was a dumby Id (unsure if you will see this comment) as I did not set up the method to transfer it from the Search.js component yet.

Thank you so much again

Comment: @SylwiaMakuch Thank you for providing a link to your GitHub repo. I just opened up a pull request on it :)